# Compiler tells me he cannot resolve Singleton method

Tags: java, android, singleton

I'm coding a app on Android Studio and the compiler tells me he cannot resolve my singleton method. I've tried using both pre-J2SE 6 singleton implementation and pos-J2SE 6 implementation using enum and in both cases the issue happens.

Here is how I'm coding (this is a simple example, I'm doing the same thing in my 
Singleton except he has more methods etc):

```
public class Singleton {

    private static final Singleton instance = new Singleton();
    private boolean aaa;

    private Singleton() {}

    public static Singleton getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    public void bbb(){}

}
```

OR

```
public enum Singleton{

    INSTANCE {

        private boolean aaa;       

        public void bbb(){}

    }

}
```

And in another class in the same package I'm coding

```
public class MapHandler implements OnMapClickListener
    Singleton abc = Singleton.getInstance();

    abc.bbb();
    // rest of code
}
```

Compiler tells me cannot resolve symbol bbb()

What I'm doing wrong? I'm asking this because this is a simple task and everyone else do this in the same way but I've searched on web about this specific case and I've found no answer for this =S

Comment: Android Studio default compiler who is javac right? Did you thought I was using jack?

Comment: I added a bit of code from your image in the comment below. It is essential to address all the problems you're facing.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you should code it:

```
public enum Singleton {
    INSTANCE;

    private boolean aaa;       
    public void bbb(){}
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Singleton abc = Singleton.INSTANCE;
        abc.bbb();
    }
}
```

Note that the `bbb` method needs to be declared as a method of the `enum` not a local method within the instance.

When you declare an enum constant with a class body like this:

```
public enum Singleton {
    INSTANCE {
        private boolean aaa;       
        public void bbb(){}
    };
}
```

you are implicitly declaring an anonymous inner class that extends the `enum` class.  The stuff inside the class body is part of the anonymous inner class, not the `enum`.  That means that the `bbb` method is not declared for the `enum`, and is effectively inaccessible ... unless you use reflection to call it.

(This is equivalent to declaring a public method in an anonymous class which doesn't correspond to any method in the parent type hierarchy.  It is there ... but you can't name it in Java code.)

Comment: The issue isn't solved, I've got some pics, here: http://imgur.com/a/CuwhR (this is the class who uses the singleton) and http://imgur.com/a/XwbTQ (this is the singleton) =S

Comment: I can't read those images. Put your code and the error messages into the question as >> TEXT <<.

Comment: Hum there's nothing different from what you told me to do, I did exact what you said, I just used imgur to show you that even doing the way you told me the compiler still cannot resolve it, printing a message (he didn't print the cannot resolve symbol on logcat by the way) =S

Comment: @TadeuAriasVillares, the remaining problem you have has nothing to do with the singleton. You're using the instance improperly in the class and that's why it can't be resolved.

Comment: @TadeuAriasVillares The code in this answer compiles and runs fine. See [IDEONE](https://ideone.com/0ZPHNM) for proof.